# Randon word from text file

Tags: python, file, random, drive

I have a file.txt where my program picks one random word from many of words each time i run the program. Every line contains one word. To prevent a word showing up twice , I created another file, file2.txt so that the drawn word can be copied into file2.txt and then deleted from file.txt where the word was drawn from. 
After all the words have been drawn (as I keep running the program). I then copied all the words from file2.txt to file.txt (original file). Its like reset everything to get the program ready for next time

My question is, is this the best way of doing it, assuming I have over 1000 words?

Here is my code so far:

```
import random

mainFile = r"C:\Users\Son\file.txt"

lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open(mainFile)]   
rand = random.choice(lines)  
print(rand)

secondFile = r"C:\Users\Son\file2.txt"
```

My code so far prints the random word from file.txt. How to I save that random word to file2.txt and then delete it from file.txt.

Also I want all the words in file2.txt to be copied back to file.txt when I close the program or when all the word in file.txt are finished. then the program should print no more word in file.txt

Comment: Can you post some code for your question, demonstrating what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I have added some codes. please have a look again

Answer (score 0):

1,000 (or even 100,000) words are usually small enough to fit into memory.

You can use:

```py
PATH = r'file1.txt'

with open(PATH, 'r') as f:
    unique_words = set(f.read().splitlines())

with open(PATH, 'w') as f:
    while unique_words:
        f.write(unique_words.pop() + '\n')
```

Comment: Would it be worth it to map the entire thing to lowercase to avoid duplicating capitalised words?

Comment: It depends on the needs of the programmer :) I don't think it will result in a significant performance penalty, but your choices should be based on the needs and the size of the input.

Comment: Thank you for your solution well appreciated. I have added some codes to my question please have a look for me. how do I blend your code with mine. Also I ran your code but did get any output.